# Lotto generator javascript

Tags: javascript, random

Hallo by lotto generator code I got some numbers double in one "generate" cycle. This is the code:

```
function lottery() {
    for (var i=0; i<=7; i++) {
        var lottery = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49);
        document.getElementById ("lotto" + i).innerHTML = lottery;
    }
}
```

Who knows where is the problem? Thank You!

Comment: You need to somehow save which numbers you have already generated.

Comment: Now I know what I'll be using every Mittwoch and Samstag...

Comment: @Michael you better use a better random generator then. Eg: random.org

Comment: Yes, might be true... @zerkms

Comment: Thanks for the link @zerkms, they even have a lottery number creator. I will be rich soon...

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun: `O(N)` solution (other posted are `O(N^2)`)

It uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and then after the first `7` elements have been shuffled it takes them as is.

So, no need to check if any of the numbers have already been drawn:

```
const arr = Array(50).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);
const DRAW = 7;

const rand = (from, to) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from;

for (let i = 0; i < DRAW; ++i) {
  const r = rand(i, arr.length - 1);
  [arr[r], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[r]];
}

const selected = arr.slice(0, DRAW);
```

References:

- [Online demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=const%20arr%20%3D%20Array(50).fill(0).map((_%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20i)%3B%0Aconst%20DRAW%20%3D%207%3B%0A%0Aconst%20rand%20%3D%20(from%2C%20to)%20%3D%3E%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20(to%20-%20from%20%2B%201))%20%2B%20from%3B%0A%0Afor%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%207%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20r%20%3D%20rand(i%2C%20arr.length%20-%201)%3B%0A%20%20%5Barr%5Br%5D%2C%20arr%5Bi%5D%5D%20%3D%20%5Barr%5Bi%5D%2C%20arr%5Br%5D%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(arr.slice(0%2C%207)))

Answer (score 1):

Like @JNK commented, you need to store used values to avoid using them again.

The easiest way to do this would be to store them in an array, and check if they've been used.

```
function lottery() {
    var used = [];
    for (var i=0; i<=7; i++) {

        var lottery;
        while(true) { // this loop keeps going until a new number is found
            lottery = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49);
            var newNum = true;
            for(var j=0; j<used.length; j++) {
                if(used[j] == lottery) { 
                    newNum = false;  // if already used, set newNum to false
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(newNum) { // if not already used, then add num to used array
                used.push(lottery);
                break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById ("lotto" + i).innerHTML = lottery;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another possible way is described here: http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/javascript-challenge-lotto-number-generator/

Comment: @JNK Yeah I know this isn't the most efficient way... but it was the most straightforward way I thought of. And I really like those optimizations in that link.

Answer (score 1):

All credits to JNK for this one from his link. This isn't very intuitive (it's minimized, like in code golf), but it's an interesting solution.

Optimized random number generator (86 bytes):

```
var getRandomLottoNumbers = function () { 
    var n=[],i=0;
    for(;++i<50;)
        n.push(i);
    for(;--i>6;)
        n.splice(i*Math.random()|0,1);
    return n
};
```

Full explanation [here](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/javascript-challenge-lotto-number-generator/).

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach as the others, however just using one loop.

```
function lottery() {
  var winners = [];
  while (winners.length < 7) {
    var lottery = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49);
    if (winners.indexOf(lottery) === -1) {
      winners.push(lottery);
      document.getElementById ("lotto" + winners.length).innerHTML = lottery;
    }
  }
}
```